# How to make TimeField timezone-aware?

Tags: django

There are occasions when you need to collect a time from a user without collecting an associated date. For example, if the user is configuring a repeating event that runs every day at the same time. Django's `TimeField` doesn't play with timezones though. However, in this particular case (and probably any time you record a time by itself), timezone is an important factor. So, how do you store a timezone-aware time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is you don't. For a time to be timezone aware, it has to have a date associated with it. Think of daylight savings... My solution for this was to use a `DateTimeField` on the model and to override the form like so:

```
# models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    time_of_day = models.DateTimeField()


# form_fields.py
from django.forms.util import from_current_timezone, to_current_timezone
from django.utils import timezone

class TzAwareTimeField(forms.fields.TimeField):
    def prepare_value(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
            value = to_current_timezone(value).time()
        return super(TzAwareTimeField, self).prepare_value(value)

    def clean(self, value):
        value =  super(TzAwareTimeField, self).to_python(value)
        dt = to_current_timezone(timezone.now())
        return dt.replace(
            hour=value.hour, minute=value.minute,
            second=value.second, microsecond=value.microsecond)


# forms.py
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    time_of_day = TzAwareTimeField()
```

Comment: Your opening statement (and Django’s behaviour) isn’t consistent with how Python handles `time` objects. A Python `time` object may have a `tzinfo` field, allowing for a timezone-aware `time` object with no associated date, which _is_ useful in some circumstances, like when the date is stored elsewhere. I just came across this issue with `open_time` and `close_time` `TimeField`s on a `Day` model in Django. Those times would ideally be timezone-aware, but can’t be because Django doesn’t support that.

Comment: This is old, but still useful, so I want to point out that I think you need to wrap the return value of the `clean` method in `from_current_timezone`.

Comment: @josh I know it's late, but other people may read this. Your assert that a timezone needs a date is false. There is a difference between a point in time (datetime) and a time of day(time). 11:00, as in "Every Friday at 11:00", is represented by a time. That time may be joined with many different dates to make a point in time, whereupon you can consider DST, if you need to convert to another time zone. Try scheduling an international meeting for Fridays at 11:00, and you'll quickly see you need to know the time zone, but not the date.

Comment: How to do the same for DateField?

Comment: @josh is correct, while a python `time` object can have `tzinfo` associated with it, that value is informational only. It is *not possible* to convert from one timezone to another without knowing a date as well. For example, it's currently 3:45PM PDT as I type this, which is 22:00 UTC in the fall but during the summer the same time of day here would be 23:00 UTC.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested and incomplete:

```
class TimeFieldWithZone(TimeField):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        if (connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'] == 
            'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'):
            return 'time with time zone'
        raise Exception('Unsupported database type')

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(TimeFieldWithZone, self).get_db_prep_value(
                value, *args, **kwargs)
        except ValueError:
            return six.text_type(value)
```

This will use Postgres' `time with time zone` datatype.  It will break if you pass it a string in the format 'HH:MM:SS.mmmmmm+HH:MM' and using auto_now will try to save a naive time (not sure if that throws an error).

## edit

In the generic backend code an exception is thrown if you try inserting a time with a timezone other than UTC.

## edit 2

I added an updated `get_db_prep_value` to convert a provided `time` with timezone into a string, but it only works if the provided timezone outputs a utc offset (which may be ambiguous without a date).

It seems `time with time zone` is a little misleading... As far as I can tell, it actually stores a time with a UTC offset and NOT a timezone.  So it'd be difficult to take the returned value, add a calendar date, and get back the proper time with regard to daylight savings time.

Answer (score 0):

1. in your model `time_field = models.TimeField(null=True)`
2. create functions that convert the time to datetime then convert it to UTC datetime then save it. Django will automatically take the time  only from the datetime.
3. Create a function that take the time stored in the database and convert it to the current timezone

- **Note**: You should activate the timezone of the current user in the [middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68418165/how-to-handling-timezones-in-django-drf-without-repeating-myself-too-much).

```
import datetime

import pytz
from django.utils import timezone


def ConvertToUTC(parsed):
    date_time = timezone.get_current_timezone().localize(parsed)
    utc_date_time = date_time.astimezone(pytz.utc)
    return utc_date_time


def ConvertToTimeZone(value, format):
    value = value.strftime(format)
    value = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, format)
    value = value.astimezone(timezone.get_current_timezone())

    return value.strftime(format)
```

4. create custom field serializer that use the functions in order to make the conversions.

```
class TimeSer(Field):
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid': 'Time has wrong format, expecting %H:%M:%S%z.',
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_internal_value(self, value):
        try:
            parsed = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%H:%M:%S')
        except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
            pass
        else:
            return ConvertToUTC(parsed)
        self.fail('invalid')

    def to_representation(self, value):

        if not value:
            return None

        if isinstance(value, str):
            return value
        if isinstance(value, datetime.time):
            return ConvertToTimeZone(value,'%H:%M:%S')

        return None
```